# How to get a tuple representation of a DirectProduct in GAP?

Tags: group-theory, gap

**Question.**
Is there any way to get and use a tuple representation of a `DirectProduct`?

**Explaination.**
Let's assume we have groups $G, H$ which are cyclic group and symmetric group respectively.  Let's take $L$ as a direct product of $G$ and $H$.
I am aware of `Projection` and `Embedding` functions as the example below presents.

```
gap> G := CyclicGroup(6);
<pc group of size 6 with 2 generators>
gap> H := SymmetricGroup(6);
Sym( [ 1 .. 6 ] )
gap> L := DirectProduct(G,H);
<group of size 4320 with 4 generators>
gap> Embedding(L,1);
MappingByFunction( <pc group of size 6 with 
2 generators>, <group of size 4320 with 4 generators>, function( elm ) ... end )
gap> Image(Embedding(L,1));
<group of size 6 with 2 generators>
gap> Image(Embedding(L,2));
<group of size 720 with 2 generators>
gap>
```

My goal is to take an exact element of $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ and get an element $(g,h) \in L$. I have noticed there is an object called `DirectProductElement`, but there is no documentation about it.

Comment: @DerekHolt, Don't you mean?
`Image(Embedding(L, 1), GeneratorsOfGroup(G)[1]);`?

Comment: So, either I do not understand or your code does not compile.

Comment: OK, I'll write it as an answer, using your example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
gap> G := CyclicGroup(6);;                                                     
gap> H := SymmetricGroup(6);;
gap> L := DirectProduct(G,H);;
gap> g:=Random(G);;
gap> h:=Random(H);;
gap> m1 := Embedding(L,1);;
gap> m2 := Embedding(L,2);;
gap> Image(m1,g) * Image(m2,h);
DirectProductElement( [ f1, (3,5,4,6) ] )
```

Comment: This is the answer that works and it gives what I wanted. 

Actually, getting back to your comment. In your comment `m1` was not `Embedding`, but an `Image`. 
That's the reason, I doubt your code in your comment will work.

Thank you Derek!

Comment: OK, I,'ll delete the comment!